# How Laravel models use function chaining?

Tags: laravel

I am working on Laravel models kind of thing, I am not able to understand how Laravel models use `function chaining` when the base model class is `abstract`. Please provide me some suitable explanation example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cloud you please share a code fragment explaining what you are referring to ?

Comment: @Moppo: I am trying to implement Model part in a frame work. So I am referring the model functionality of Laravel, but not able to understand how it works. My code is not properly organized so there is no use of sharing that code.

Comment: ok. I was referring to the Laravel code.i think that speaking of 'models' is too broad to understand what you're referring to

Comment: Yeah I know, will you suggest some good link to get the idea?

Comment: i'm expecting you to suggest some code  to better understand what you're asking in your question :)

Comment: OK, I will add the code and ping you. I hope you will suggest me some way :)